# Avoid inlining of explcitly instantiated std::vector<T> code? (Visual Studio C++ 2008)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, stl, build

I want to decrease the size of .obj files in a large project I'm working on (I know that linker removes duplicate definitions, but I want to speed up the build process). One of the reasons for their size is that each class which uses `std::vector<double>` or `std::vector<std::string>` ends up compiling the code of this class and placing it in its .obj file. I tried to explicitly instantiate `std::vector<double>` and use `extern template` declaration, but it doesn't work -- `std::vector` in Visual Studio C++ STL has all methods inline. Short of modifying the STL code (which I won't do), is there any way to force the compiler not to inline instantiated methods and to use the externally instantiated version of `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: Since when does Microsoft’s C++ compiler even support `extern template`? As far as I know, it’s simply ignored.

Comment: It's not. I tried it on VS 2008 (with SP1) and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is writing an inclusion header that defines the `std::vector` template (but not its members, those only need to be declared) and include that instead of the `vector` standard header.

Then you can explicitly instantiate `std::vector<whatever>` in a separate compilation unit and link against that.

To explicitly instantiate the template, don’t use `extern template` (that won’t work), just use the following:

```
#include <vector> // The standard header, not your forward-declaration!

template class std::vector<double>;
```

Comment: @quant_dev Forget what I said, it might just work (but your experiments suggest that it doesn’t, in this case). Then again, so does the instantiation without `extern`.

Comment: Yes, it works when the templates do not include method definitions in the class definition.

Comment: But -- if I just forward-declare `std::vector`, to call its methods I need to include `<vector>`, and then it's game over.

Comment: @quant_dev No, you don’t need to include `<vector>` if you explicitly instantiate the template in another compilation unit (except in that compilation unit). This works just fine, I used the same technique not two days ago.

Comment: @quant_dev Also, wrong choice of work: you need to define `std::vector` in the forward header, it’s true. You just don’t need to define its members, it’s enough to declare them.

Comment: If I understand correctly the suggestion here is not a forward declaration of vector but instead a #include of a cut down version of the vector header, where all implementation of methods has been removed i.e. a full class declaration (with all public methods) but with no definitions.  Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the best option (daramarak's suggestion would amount to the above + deriving another class from std::vector).

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest now I would consider a *hack*, as *it convolute the code to achieve a compiler optimization*. Compiler flags should be investigated before you try this.

All in all what compiler puts into the obj files is compiler dependent, but I would suggest to try to inherit an specialization of the vector, and use this specialization. I can imagine that this will make the compiler create an obj file containing the specialization of the vector, allowing all users of the wrapped vector to use this instead.

Answer (score -1):

It can't possibly do that unless you alter the `vector` header or provide its equivalent that only contains declarations. Otherwise whenever you `#include` file `vector` its contents gets into the including file and gets compiled and the templates are instantiated at first use. Then the linker eliminates the duplicates. It's how C++ compilation works, you can't do anything here.

Comment: It's not exactly like that. If the template class does not contain method definitions INSIDE the class definition, then I can add the `extern template` declaration AFTER the class definition, and the compiler avoids instantiating the template at point of use, trusting in the `extern template` declaration. It's the inlining of the methods which gets me.